# SugarCRM adding fields from custom modules to email templates

Tags: php, email, sugarcrm

I am trying to add a fields from a custom module to the Email Templates in SugarCRM (Version 6.5). I have followed the advice at:

http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f3/adding-custom-module-insert-variable-dropdownlist-email-template-50158/

However any changes I make to the Email.php file don't seem to be doing anything. I have even tried putting `die()` into the area I'm supposed to make the changes but the emails send fine.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious, maybe this file is no longer involved in sending emails using the templates. Any ideas would be much appreciated!